# What's an easy and fast way to search for any sequence of numbers (e.g. 334455) in my 1 GB txt file listing the first billion digits of pi?

Tags: search, pi

This is in a Linux environment, in case that matters.

pi.txt is a text file listing the first billion digits of pi, all in one line (no line breaks, no spaces.)

Right now to find the character position of an arbitrary sequence, e.g. 334455, I'm doing this:

LANG=C grep -aob '334455' pi.txt | head -1

It's pretty darn slow, and I think I've optimized grep as much as possible in this case. Consumes a CPU at 100% and takes about 15 seconds.

What's a better solution?

Comment: (Off topic) Use some online tool, for example https://www.angio.net/pi/.

Comment: Grep is ultimately limited by file read speed. How fast is `cat pi.txt > /dev/null`?

Comment: cat'ing pi into null takes less than a second... so I'm not sure that's the right test. I think grep could possibly work better if the file weren't a single line. for example, I can't tell grep to *stop* looking after it finds my first instance, because grep will read a minimum of one line.

Comment: @Canton But you can't break lines, imagine you are searching "92" in `14159\n26535`.

Answer (score 1):

*This answer maybe off-topic. If it does, I will delete my answer.*

You may try to pre-build a [search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_tree) to improve your search speed, for example a [prefix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), which may efficiently collapse the search time.

But, as of my think currently, build a search tree for Pi is nearly equal to build a dictionary / cache for all queries...

Below is just a simple summarize of https://www.angio.net/pi/how.html.

Using `grep` directly, is more likely to do a [linear search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_search), which is very slow and "fat".

- For "fat": According to ASCII, we know numbers lies in the area of `0x3*`, which the left nybble `3` is duplicated for all times inside the text representation of Pi, which can be collapsed if we just want to do search. For example, storing `14159265` in disk can be optimized as storing `0x14 0x15 0x92 0x65` instead of ASCII storing `0x31 0x34 0x31 0x35 0x39 0x32 0x36 0x35`.
- For slow: If an input is long, then we can pack the first 4 digits, the same way as we pack Pi in the previous. Then we can do one comparison for 2 digits compared to the naïve linear search that compares only 1 digit per comparison.

Then, they done some benchmark and used a mixed search:

- For search with length <= 5, they do linear search as previously described.
- For longer search, they do an index search with the help of [suffix array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array).

Then, they [rewrite the search engine from C++ to Go](https://da-data.blogspot.com/2013/05/improving-pi-searchers-speed-by-moving.html).

Answer (score -1):

How about reading the file once into memory first?

```
A=$(<file)
```